# ERROR: Build step failed with exception net.sf.json.JSONException: null object while bulding and publishing docker image

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, cicd

I have created a springboot project with docker file. I have tomcat running in my windows machine. I have jenkins running inside webapps folder of tomcat server. I have created a job in jenkins and integrated github and added build and publish plogin to build and publish the docker image. Now when i am building the job. The project build is successfull using maven and a war is created but image build and publish is failing again and again. Below error is coming. I am not able to locate the DockerRegistryEndpoint.java file.

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
net.sf.json.JSONException: null object 
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.verifyIsNull(JSONObject.java:2688)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.element(JSONObject.java:1733)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.element(JSONObject.java:1716)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:2328)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.DockerRegistryToken$1.call(DockerRegistryToken.java:150)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.DockerRegistryToken$1.call(DockerRegistryToken.java:125)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:47)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.DockerRegistryToken.newKeyMaterialFactory(DockerRegistryToken.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.DockerRegistryEndpoint.newKeyMaterialFactory(DockerRegistryEndpoint.java:259)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.DockerRegistryEndpoint.newKeyMaterialFactory(DockerRegistryEndpoint.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.DockerRegistryEndpoint.newKeyMaterialFactory(DockerRegistryEndpoint.java:236)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.executeCmd(DockerBuilder.java:455)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.executeCmd(DockerBuilder.java:431)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.buildAndTag(DockerBuilder.java:373)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.exec(DockerBuilder.java:311)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.access$100(DockerBuilder.java:291)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder.perform(DockerBuilder.java:262)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:816)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:164)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:524)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1897)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Build step 'Docker Build and Publish' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```